# How to overcome Network Failure error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am developing a CI app for a client with MySQL as back end.

The client has 8 shops. **For each shop, there is a local server**, and additionally, there is **one central server, which is placed at the Head Quarters** (HQ).

The problem i am facing is,

- At the time of **network failure at a shop**, the **billing and other
  processes should work; without central server**. Once the network is
  back, they **need it to sync with HQ Server**.

**Those who clicking on too board on close can you please say what all details you need? I am not getting that part thats why, please add that as comment, i will do it**

Comment: i suggest hiring a senior developer which has experience on this, its too dangerous to get guidance from this question, because, it *is* too broad and no answer on this question can be *practically useful* on a PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT WITH MONEY TRANSACTIONS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in shop environment, you should cope to this requirements having basic data into the single store (eg. items, promotions, parameters) and setting up a database synchronization between local stores and center db ...

If you have MySQL in each store and as central DB, you can set up a MySQL replication, otherwise take a look at [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org) that is in short the missing component that can perfectly fit your scenario, since :

> SymmetricDS is open source software for both file and database
>   synchronization with support for multi-master replication, filtered
>   synchronization, and transformation across the network in a
>   heterogeneous environment. It supports multiple subscribers with one
>   direction or bi-directional, asynchronous data replication. It uses
>   web and database technologies to replicate data as a scheduled or near
>   real-time operation. The software was designed to scale for a large
>   number of nodes, work across low-bandwidth connections, and withstand
>   periods of network outage. It works with most operating systems, file
>   systems, and databases, including Oracle, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL,
>   MS SQL Server (including Azure), IBM DB2, H2, HSQLDB, Derby, Firebird,
>   Interbase, Informix, Greenplum, SQLite (including Android), Sybase
>   ASE, and Sybase ASA (SQL Anywhere) databases.